# May I see an example of a properly formatted Magento CSV with grouped products?

Tags: import

I would like to review it to take the same approach on a DB that Im scrubbing.  We are moving a large amount of old html table data to a DB. I've already exported a base file for the headers. I'm looking for one that has grouped products so I can review the correct fields and expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already created the products, the following is the crucial part for assigning simple products (SKUs `1234568` and `1234569`) to a grouped product (SKU `1234567`):

```
sku,_type,_associated_sku,_associated_position,_associated_default_qty
1234567,grouped,1234568,1,1
,,1234569,2,1
```

You can find more details about the import format at http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/.